# Is this a certain kind of oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

I was having a ton of trouble understanding oscillators, and I needed something to power a tank circuit at its resonant frequency.

I decided to just come up with something myself and this is what I arrived at.  I tested it and it seems to work great.

[image]

I know that there are many named oscillators and I wanted to know if anyone could tell me what other oscillators this might be similar to or how you might classify it.

Comment: Reminds me of a [Colpitts oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circuit diagram looks a bit weird so I took the liberty of redrawing it.
Your circuit looks like a oscillator that produces a pulse output at the collector of Q1. This pulse will excite the tank circuit and provided the loading is small will cause it to go into oscillation. If you compare it with the circuit below it you will see the same basic configuration of PNP and NPN transistors mirror imaged. The orginal circuit came from the 1950's and was a curious circuit called Garner's oscillator. (http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/michael/blog/0502/#garnosc) The circuit shown below is borrowed from the site for completeness and yes I do know it its not drawn correctly as it shows two PNP transistors but read the article.
[image]